# How do you reset App Engine's appcfg authentication state?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want AppEngine's `appcfg.py` to forget the authentication state so I can login with a different account. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `.appcfg_oauth2_tokens` and `.appcfg_cookies` files in your home directory.

i.e.

```
rm ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens
rm ~/.appcfg_cookies
```